# Compare COUNT results before and after operation/load in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare

I need help for one of my cases.

1. Lets say that I have one table with only one column named CustomerID with 1500 records.
2. The CustomerID table is loaded in DB 2 times per day - 10am and 10pm
3. I want to compare the CustomerID table in the morning (10am) with the one in (10pm)

`SELECT COUNT(*) from CustomerID -- 10 AM / 1500 records.`

`SELECT COUNT(*) from CustomerID -- 10 PM / 1510 records.`

I want to check for these 10 extra records - only the count, nothing more.

The main idea is to keep track on the table and if there are no new records in 10 PM - to tell the responsible person that the table is "broken", because the table should be a growing count number with every load.

Thanks!

Comment: If the table only has 1 column how do you know what rows are the new ones? If you don't know, why do you think the RDBMS will? You *can't* do this with only 1 column, unless that column is the date and time the row was inserted (and let's be honest, if it is, it's useless data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this recently for multiple DBs and table, but can show you how to do it for just one table.

Instructions:

1. Create a stored procedure using the query below (update w/ your db and table
   name)

   *You will need to create the table before being able to run this
2. Put this on a job schedule for 10a and 10p
3. Check daily or create a visualization/dashboard using this new table as a data
   source to display whether everything was loaded as it should have been

Query:

```
use [YOUR DB NAME]
go

create procedure [YOURSCHEMA.YOUR_NEW_AUDIT_TABLE_NAME] as

insert into [TABLE_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_CREATE_FOR_TRACKING]
select schema_name(schema_id) as [schemaname],
       [tables].name as [tablename],
       sum([partitions].[rows]) as [totalrowcount],
       getdate() as date_checked
from sys.tables as [tables]
    join sys.partitions as [partitions] on [tables].[object_id] = [partitions].[object_id] and [partitions].index_id in ( 0, 1 )
where [tables].name = '[TABLE_NAME_YOU_WANT_TRACKED]'
group by schema_name(schema_id), [tables].name;


go;
```

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome! I think this should do the job!